# Why Inotify is unable to add watch

Tags: x11, software-installation, inotify

I have been trying to install teamviewer on RHEL 6 machine. The installation went fine. When I try to run teamviewer, it terminates immediately after showing the GUI. I went to /var/log/teamviewer/TeamViewer9_Logfile.log and the last two lines of the log file says:

```
S0! INotify: unable to add watch for /tmp/.X11-unix
S0!! XSocketSessionObserver: caught exception 'add-watch' 2 Errorcode=2
```

I am not sure why INotify is unable to add watch for /tmp/.X11-unix. This file/directory does not exist, could that be the reason? In that case, how this gets created?

Comment: Are you running it as root or a regular user? http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/how-to-install-teamviewer-on-centos-6-rhel-6.html#axzz35BHpKEKh

Comment: Same problem reported here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1395059

Comment: running it as regular user

Comment: Seems like a bug w/ TeamViewer 9 to me. The fix involves this, recompiling lib32-glibc without enable-lock-ellision. I'd check TeamViewer's website for a fix or downgrade if you're desperate.

Comment: hmm, thanks, my teamviewer installation is on a 64 bit server, not on a something with a Intel 4th Gen Haswell processors (I guess they are in newer Lenovo laptops?)

Comment: Do you know how to recompile lib32-glibc? I have never done it before.

Comment: I think the TeamViewer s/w is still 32-bit which can run on 64-bit.

Comment: On RHEL you generally don't mess with glibc libraries.

Comment: yes I know that, I was wondering how to "recompile" gcc.

Comment: If you really wanted to recompile this I'd download the source RPM and then extract the .spec file from it and add the necessary compiler options to that file, then rebuild it using `rpmbuild`.